# disfunctional recursion in shell

Tags: recursion, sh, ksh

I have tried to make this as simple as possible, I am still trying to understand why recursion fails in the following example.

```
#!/bin/sh

foo()
{
echo "Enter a number"
read num
if [ $num -eq 1 ]; then
foo $num
fi
echo "Hi"
sleep 1
}
while true
do
foo
done
```

simply hit '1'(you will enter the if statement and recursion), you will end up executing "hi" twice or to that point as many number of times you enter '1'. How can I counter such an issue?

sample execution

```
Enter a number
1
Enter a number
 1
Enter a number
2
Hi
Hi
Hi
```

Comment: The recursion does not fail, it does what you ask for. To counter that issue, use a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: You're invoking `foo $num` recursively, but why do you pass `$num` as an argument to `foo()` while `foo()` does not reference it (`$1`) in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The recursion is not failing. When a recursive function is called the execution before the call of function happens and the execution after the function happens once the function returns.

The part of the code which prints "Hi" is one which will always get executed , 
consider the case have you not called the function recursively , the "Hi" would have printed , same thing is happening now.
If you are going to call the function - foo n number of times the "Hi" will be printed n number of times.